# I copied the exact same code, but mine does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3R0q.jpg)

I am using Java 8 update 251

The error that shows up:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   Index 0 out of bounds for length 0    at
>   first_project.main(first_project.java:6)

Comment: it appears you are new to java, right ? Do you know any other programming language already ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 2):

The error is displayed as you are not passing any parameter while running the program. Try running the program from command line and passing argument. Eg:

```
c:\> java MyFirstJavaProgram arg0_value
```

or you can provide argument in Run Configuration of eclipse as well.

Comment: The official term would be "command-line arguments" or "program arguments". Googling "Eclipse ..." (Using either term) would provide the information needed to understand this. Either way, +1, although I recommend giving the OP info for expanding on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

This program is expecting a command line argument; if you run this with Eclipse it will cause this issue.
You need run this program from the shell with the proper arguments.

Compile file:

```cmd
javac java_filepathofFile argument
```

Use java to run:

```cmd
java class_filepathofFile argument
```